# sass mixin getting error in color string

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to unquote a variable that is being passed in as a paramter to a mixin and I keep getting this error. I've used unquote to not make i a string but I still get this error, I'm trying to preserve the hsla and have a fallback color can someone help me please

error:

```
/*Error: $color1: "hsla(118, 77%, 53%, 1)" is not a color for `mix'
  on line 5 of sass/base/mixins.scss, in `color'
```

sass:

```
@include color(background unquote("hsla(118, 77%, 53%, 1)"))

@mixin color($properties...){
    @each $property in $properties {
        $value: nth($property, 2);
        $color: unquote($value);
        #{nth($property, 1)}:mix($color, $color); // error here on $color                   
        #{nth($property, 1)}:nth($property, 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the question your previous question was marked as a duplicate of already addresses this.  It specifically states that once you create a string, you can't use it in color manipulation functions.

Comment: Ok so how do I preserve hsla and then have a fall back could you please show or help me

Comment: What's wrong with having hex color format?

Comment: I'm learning sass and I just want to know how to do this could you show me how to do it please